# Passing Variables in Python, Flask

Tags: python, variables, flask

I am trying to understand Python and passing variables. I am trying to pass an id for an 'action'. I can create the action and see the is there but I do not understand how to take the id and pass it from one form to another. If anyone could point me in the right direction would be great.

Views.py

```
#g.user.nickname passes in the nickname for a refernce
@app.route('/edit', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def edit():
    form = EditForm(g.user.nickname)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        g.user.nickname = form.nickname.data
        g.user.about_me = form.about_me.data
        db.session.add(g.user)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Your changes have been saved.')
        return redirect(url_for('edit'))
    elif request.method != "POST":
        form.nickname.data = g.user.nickname
        form.about_me.data = g.user.about_me
    return render_template('edit.html', form=form)

#Don't understand how to create a variable to pass a reference from post.html 
@app.route('/action_request', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def action_requests():
    form = EditReqForm()
    return render_template('action_request.html',
                            form=form)
```

Post.html

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <tr>

        <td>
            <p>Raised by <a href="{{ url_for('user', nickname=action.author.nickname) }}">{{ action.raised_by }} </a>on
                {{ action.date_raised.strftime('%d-%m-%Y') }}:</p>
            #Trying to generate reference of action id to pass to ActionReqForm
            <p><a href="{{ url_for('action_requests', id=action.id)}}"><strong>
                Issue:</strong>{{
                action.issue }}</a></p>
            <p><strong>Source: {{action.id}}</strong>{{ action.source }}</p>

            <p><strong>Immediate Action: </strong>{{ action.immediate_action }}</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `action_requests` is rendering with `form=form` in the namespace. So if `id` and `source` are part of `form` perhaps try `form['action']`?? I am only guessing, since I don't see anything related to `action`, or `action.id`, or `action.immediate_action` with the code that you have posted. See: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/signals/

Comment: the function expects list of variables, since you are only using `action` it would expect `render_template('action_request.html', action=action)` but since you only have your form, you could add the values as hidden input fields to your posted edit form and pass them one-by-one from there: `render_template('action_request.html', action_date=form.action_date.data, action_issue=form.action_issue.data, ... etc ... )`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions I think I can explain a little better. In the edit user code you pass in data by doing the following, "form.nickname.data = g.user.nickname". This fills the form data with the nickname. What I  want to do is create a variable similar to g.user but for actions. I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the solution,
request.args.get()